# Oracle Internet Directory (OID) hardening

Tags: hardening, integrity, confidentiality, oracle, ldap

What are best practices, recommendations, required reading for securing/hardening an Oracle internet directory?

note: OID is compatible with LDAP version 3.

Comment: Maybe this question is better if you ask it for general LDAP hardening?

Comment: OID requires anonymous search to be enabled if you want to register a database in it. Technotes ID 305371.1, 455031.1, 262560.1 and 456766.1 have more information. I gave up after weeks of hard work, looking at ldap traces and fidling with ACI ...

Answer (score 2):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/network.901/a90151/security.htm

Answer (score 0):

Consider some topics from [LDAP Server Security](http://ldapmaven.com/2013/07/31/ldap-hardening-server-security-so-administrators-can-sleep-at-night/) as a possible starting point.